# User not listed in root's home folder (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: root, user-management, 19.10

I've upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10 and after adding the following, I've gotten myself in a login loop, where I can enter the password and the screen goes blank:

$ gedit ~/.profile

Added the following to the bottom:
xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00" 64.11 1024 1080 1184 1344 768 769 772 795 -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1024x768_60.00

It immediately recognized the resolution and was working fine, until I rebooted it.

When I'm on root's home folder and ls, I dont see the user listed.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Root's home folder (`/root`) is exactly that - it shouldn't contain anything related to other users. Other user's home folders are usually in `/home`.

Comment: I see 2 other users there, but not the one I try logging into when booting on GUI.

Comment: Perhaps you have an unmounted /home partition?

Comment: I've hit Ctrl + Alt + F3 and edited the am file, deleting those 2 lines and voilà! It's back up! I now need to find how to have the added resolution remembered during boot. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to set the resolution using xrandr? Does it not work through Settings - Displays? If not, then you could probably add the command to your autostart programs.

Comment: I ended up doing that. It wouldn't auto detect... 
Solution was: accessed the file via terminal login and removed those lines.